# Why is firebase giving me an error on deploy?

Tags: javascript

I finished my website and wanted to host it for free in **firebase**, I followed all the steps but it won't work .
When I type the command "firebase serve" to see how would my website look before deploying it and it gives me :

> 404 error

Ps: I  don't know if it matters but my website includes 2 **html** files , 4 **css** and 1 **javascript**.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `firebase.json` file and make sure the public property is referencing the path correctly.

The `public` attribute specifies which directory to deploy to Firebase Hosting so it might be the problem in this case:

```
{
   "hosting": {
   "public": "./dist/your-app",
   "ignore": [
     "firebase.json",
     "**/.*",
     "**/node_modules/**"
   ],
   "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```